# Docx template php mysql multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, templates, ms-word

I have written a code that get info from the database and put it in an docx template. But i want it to put all the records instead of just one.

Here is my code:

```
// New Word Document
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$template = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('template.docx');

$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error Connect to Database");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("word");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
        // Add more rows / cells
        $template->setValue('CustomerID',$objResult["CustomerID"]);
        $template->setValue('Name',$objResult["Name"]);
        $template->setValue('Email',$objResult["Email"]);
        $template->setValue('CountryCode',$objResult["CountryCode"]);
        $template->setValue('Budget',$objResult["Budget"]);
        $template->setValue('Used',$objResult["Used"]);
    }
$template->save('CreateWord2.docx');
```

My template look like this:

**template.docx**

```
Customer Report<br/>
CustomerID  Name       Email    CountryCode Budget      Used<br/>
«${CustomerID}» «${Name}» «${Email}» «${CountryCode}» «${Budget}» «${Used}»
```

The output word document is like this:

**CreateWord2.docx**

```
CustomerID  |Name   |   Email   |CountryCode    |Budget     Used|<br/>
C001            George     a@sk.com     GB              10.000      3.000
```

And i want it like this:

```
CustomerID  |Name      |Email   |CountryCode    |Budget     |Used|<br/>
C001            George     g@sk.com     GB              10.000      3.000<br/>
C002            Robert     r@sk.com     NL              16.000      4.000
```